# How to update the record's dropdownlist based on precedence?

Tags: sql, sql-update, case-when

I have a dropdownlist which contains:

```
Rank1 
Rank2
Rank3
Rank4
```

and update button.

I have the following record like

```
id    name    rank
1     chetan    1
2     ajay      3
3     kelly     2
```

I want to write update SQL query in such a way that:

- when I want to update the  rank of chetan(rank1) to rank2 then it should not be updated.
- rank3 can be update to rank1 and rank2
- rank4 can update to rank1 rank2 and rank3
- rank2 should not be update to rank3 and rank4.

It's like top preference. Higher level ranks should not be updated to lower ranks but lower ranks can be updated to higher ranks.

I tried the query using `Case when` but it's not working:

```
 update cmp set cmp.rank = case when 'Rank4' Then update cmp set cmp.rank='Rank3'                             or cmp.rank='Rank2' or cmp.rank='Rank1' else cmp.rank end,
                cmp.rank=case when 'Rank3' Then update cmp set cmp.rank='Rank2' or cmp.rank='Rank1' else cmp.rank end,
                ...
```

Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: `rank3 can be update to rank1 and rank2` ... if rank3 can map to more than one value, then how can we possibly give you a query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen...we can use OR in a sql query

Comment: #chetan kambli----- you should show your expected query result table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way

```
update t
   set t.rank='<passed_in_value_from_dropdown>'
 where '<passed_in_value_from_dropdown>' < t.rank
   and t.emp = '<passed_in_emp_number>'
```